# Using Appium / Python, how can I check if the Keyboard is showing or not?

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I have seen the Appium doc for **IsKeyboardShown** method in this link:

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/is-keyboard-shown/

And it says # Not supported for Python

Maybe there could be a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use **IsKeyboardShown** method? Is there any specific reason you want to check whether or not the soft keyboard is shown? You can input the text using **sendkey** method.

Comment: There was a testcase they wanted me to automate with a a step to check if Keyboard was dismissed properly but I doubt that it is actually important. From an automation perspective I don't think there is too much sense in doing so. Maybe it is a kind of bug to be detected only in manual tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `hide_keyboard` method in webdriver.py.

You can use it as e.g.:

```
self.driver.hide_keyboard()
```